# Angularjs - Error: $rootScope:infdig using custom Filter - How to avoid returning a new array?

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple custom filter to randomize the entries in an array.
The filter works, but throws an  [Error: [$rootScope:infdig]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

In the angularjs documentation it says this error results due to instantiating a new array.

**The question: How can i apply this filter by not returning a new array?** *(to avoid the digest loop error)*

Thanks for your help!
Vin

**filter:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("app")
    .filter("shuffleArray",
        shuffleArray);

function shuffleArray() {
    return function (array) {

        return array.sort(function () {
            return 0.5 - Math.random()
        });
    }

};
```

}());

**controller:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

};
```

}());

**view:**

```
 <pre> {{ vm.testArray | shuffleArray }} </pre>
```

Comment: A filter should be a mathematical function: it should always return the same value for a given array. Don't use a filter for that: angular will call your filter a lot of times. Create the random array once in the controller.

Comment: Also, note that your filter does NOT return a new array. It modifies the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply JB Nizet.

Now i came up with the following solution:

I put the shuffleArray method in a class i called "helperService".

**helperService:**

```
...

function helperService() {
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        return array.sort(function () {
            return 0.5 - Math.random()
        })
    }
    return {
        shuffleArray: shuffleArray
    };
...
```

**controller:**

```
...
vm.testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

vm.toggleShuffle = function () {
        return helperService.shuffleArray(vm.testArray);
}
...
```

**view:**

```
<button ng-click=" shuffle = vm.toggleShuffle()">toggleShuffle</button>

<pre>shuffle click result: {{ shuffle }} </pre>
```

This works perfectly fine!

So the problem seemed to be that in the view i called the shuffle() function as an expression. when put into an ng-click it works perfectly fine.

So is it in general a bad idea to put functions inside expressions in the view?

Comment: No, it's not a bad idea, if the function returns stable results. For example, calling add(2, 45) from an expression is fine is the function returns 47. But if the function returns a random value every time it's called (and it's called very often: every time angular needs to check if the value of the expression has changed), then it's a bad idea. And it's even worse if the function just doesn't return something, but modified the state of the application. Once again, expressions are evaluated very often.